# I keep receiving "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in ..."

Tags: php, parse-error

I am very new to PHP programming and I will be very thankful if anyone kindly help me out regarding the error message that I am getting on the following code snippet:

```
<option value="<?php echo $rowMC['id']; ?>" <?php echo  (isset($_POST['MainContract']) && $_POST['MainContract'] === '<?php echo $rowMC['id']; ?>' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> > <?php echo $rowMC['MainContract']; ?> </option>
```

I have checked several time that there are not any missing ; in the lines before or after and I think sth is wrong with the posted code snippet.

Comment: Missing closing ) is at least one issue. Note that their are two ('s.

Comment: Also seems to incorrectly have PHP inside strings inside PHP.. which is probably incapable of performing the desired action. I’d toss most of the code and write to a single variable above, then only emit that variable inline with the HTML "value" attribute..

Comment: I have checked several times for missing; or ( )or < >, but nothing was found. I would appreciate rewriting the correct code snippet for me

Comment: There are two (( and one ). Thus the check failed because the numbers are trivially different. Try again. I recommend starting over with a separate code block above or function call to improve readability. It should also help reveal the other error, of PHP-in-a-PHP-string.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I had missed a ), Thanks for help

Comment: After adding the missing ), now I am getting the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING) in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
<option value="<?= $rowMC['id']; ?>" <?= isset($_POST['MainContract']) && $_POST['MainContract'] === $rowMC['id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?> > <?= $rowMC['MainContract']; ?> </option>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. Remove the `;` before the `?`

Comment: Thanks Behzad, I used your code snippet but it did not work out

Comment: @user17771041 - Did you remove the extra `;` I mentioned in the comment above? And instead of just saying "did not work out", explain what actually happens.

Comment: you were right , edited code.

Comment: my apology dear @M. Eriksson, In fact, the ; that you mentioned was needed to be. According to others, I realized that I had some extra ( which I deleted it and I used the snipped sugested in answers, but I am getting a new error mesage as: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Comment: Dear @behzadmsalehi I used your code snippet and again I am getting another error message as: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in ...

Comment: @user17771041 - _"In fact, the ; that you mentioned was needed to be"_ - No, that `;` I mentioned does not "needed to be". That semi colon is literally what's causing the syntax error you just mentioned.

Comment: try it again !!!

Comment: @behzadmsalehi - I copied and pasted and it did work, Thanks for that

Comment: @M.Eriksson I replaced my code with the given code in the answer and that error disappeared and now I am getting another problem in my code that I believe I should start a new post for that. Regarding your comment, there were several ; before ? and maybe I took the wrong one. But many thanks for your kind considerations.

Comment: @behzadmsalehi your suggested code works perfectly and has no syntax error, but it has another problem. the reason I needed it, was to keep the data in an input form after submitting the form, but it is not doing that. In fact, I need to use it to make some dependent dropdown boxes. any suggestions?

Comment: did you mean that the option will never gives 'selected' option ? in this case dump your condition before the script to check if they are equvalent and in the same type ? var_dump(isset($_POST['MainContract']) && $_POST['MainContract'] === $rowMC['id']) to check it

Comment: @behzadmsalehi yes, The option does not give the selected option. After using var_dump(isset($_POST['MainContract']) && $_POST['MainContract'] === $rowMC['id']), right after selecting from first dropdown which is MainContract, I get the output as: bool(false)

Comment: ok so : var_dump(isset($_POST['MainContract'])) ? check if ever you get any $_POST data on the page? if it is false you must reconsider your used logic!

Comment: @behzadmsalehi, I have put onchange()='reload() method for the MainContract dropdown and added the javascript code as: <script>
 function reload() {
 var v1 = document.getElementById ('s1').value;
 self.location = 'indexAsli.php?MainContract='+ v1;
 }

</script> perhaps sth is wrong with this code. I should say I know nothing about javascript and I just have copied it from somewhere

Comment: you are sending mainContract as get method. 
change post variable with gets in the script .
<option value="<?= $rowMC['id']; ?>" <?= isset($_GET['MainContract']) && $_GET['MainContract'] === $rowMC['id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?> > <?= $rowMC['MainContract']; ?> </option>

Comment: @behzadmsalehi I did as you said and it is working. But if for sake of security I prefer to keep POST method in my main code, can I do some modifications in my Javascript to get the job done?

Comment: when you refresh the page u can load some parameters by the client in URL and fetch them after reload, but if you want to send parameters as posts u must request the server to do it for you, u can use ajax and other approaches. but the other approaches and arguments about your logic do not belong to this place and commenting system

Comment: @behzadmsalehi thanks, you helped me a lot today and saved me from a big headache. As I mentioned, for security reasons I prefer to use the POST method and I look for the Ajax stuff that you named. If by chance, you know some links that could save me from this trouble, I appreciate that one too. Once again, many thanks.

Comment: your welcome dear, there are many many articles around the web about topics such as ajax, request/response and etc. the best way is googling it and remember: Google is your friend!